# How can I solve dependency issue while multible depended web aplication?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, devops

How can I solve not found issue while restoring dependencies docker build? I got this issue. My file structure is that like below.

Please focus on my Dockerfile:

```
[Solution] 'xxxxx' (3 Projects)
  | 
  +-- [xxxxx.Web]
  |    |
  |    +--- xxxxx.Web.csproj (This project holds the Docker file)
  |
  +-- [xxxxx.xxxxserver]
  |    |
  |    +--- xxxxx.xxxxserver.csproj
  |
  +-- [xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client]
       |
       +--- xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client.csproj

 1. xxxxx.Web.csproj -> API
 2. xxxxx.xxxxserver/xxxxx.xxxxserver.csproj -> IdentityServer
 3. xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client/xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client.csproj -> xxxxApi.Client
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["xxxxx.Web.csproj", "./"]

COPY ["common.props", "./"]

RUN dotnet restore "xxxxx.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "xxxxx.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "xxxxx.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xxxxx.Web.dll"]
```

common.props:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CS1591;CS0436</NoWarn>
    <AbpProjectType>app</AbpProjectType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm having troubles telling this question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213343/how-can-i-solve-not-found-issue-while-restoring-dependencies-docker-build) question apart. Did you accidentally post the same question twice?

Comment: @MindSwipe Thank you for your attention. I dropped other!

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear, `common.props` was not found in the location that was expected. Make sure that, even inside your docker container, `common.props` is at the location specified inside the `EventHub.Web.csproj`. In this case located at `../../common.props`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you have the wrong path for copying files. And you also need to copy the * .sln file. Firstly check the paths.

Based on the description of the problem, it seems to me that it would be more correct to make the Dockerfile like this:

First, put the Dockerfile flush with the sln file.

and try this

```
COPY *.sln .
COPY xxxxx.Web/*.csproj ./xxxxx.Web/
COPY xxxxx.xxxserver/*.csproj ./xxxxx.xxxserver/
COPY xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client/*.csproj ./xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client/

RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .

WORKDIR /app/xxxxx.Web
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore
```

upd:
If you don't have *.sln file, just change WORKDIR to your startup project, like this:

```
COPY xxxxx.Web/*.csproj ./xxxxx.Web/
COPY xxxxx.xxxserver/*.csproj ./xxxxx.xxxserver/
COPY xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client/*.csproj ./xxxxx.xxxxApi.Client/

WORKDIR /app/xxxxx.Web

RUN dotnet restore
```

Comment: Aleksandr; Thank you for your answer, but image that how can i do that others? because I have to create image fır Identityserver and I have to create image for Httpapi.client. When I moved Dockerfile parent folder .I have no idea other images ?

Comment: Do you need make two different images? one for Identityserver and one for  Httpapi.client?

Comment: yes, absolutely because I used in AKS binding kubernetes. 5001 port for identity, 5002 for Api, and 80 port for Web

Comment: Please tell me what is common.props? This is not shown in your diagram. Is this the directory under the EventHub.Web.csproj directory?

Comment: Thank you, please show EventHub.Web.csproj, so that i can see how this project refers to common.props

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231461/discussion-between-aleksandr-kurilov-and-penguen).